# MySQL JOIN two tables and return multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. 'First' table contains 2 ids of 'second' table. v2 and v3 are second table's IDs.

**First**:

```
`id`, `mem`, `v2`, `v3`, `v2_amt`, `v3_amt`
  1, 'test',  1,     2,   '10',     '20'
  2, 'test2', 1,     2,   '10',     ''
```

**Second**:

```
`id`, `name`
  1, 'anna'
  2, 'teena'
```

When I'm joining,

```
SELECT      f.mem, s.name 

FROM        `first` f 

JOIN        second s 
    ON      f.v2 = s.id 
    AND     f.v2_amt !="" 
    AND     (f.v3 = s.id AND f.v3_amt !='') 

WHERE       f.id = '1' 

GROUP BY    s.id
```

- Currenlty it return none.

Is any way to union both tables to achieve output as following..??

```
`mem`, `name`
  test, 'anna'
  test, 'teena'
```

For fetching 2 id of first table.

```
SELECT      f.mem, s.name 

FROM        `first` f 

JOIN        second s 
    ON      f.v2 = s.id 
    AND     f.v2_amt !="" 
    AND     (f.v3 = s.id AND f.v3_amt !='') 

WHERE       f.id = '2' 

GROUP BY    s.id
```

It should return as, seems v3_amt is empty.

```
`mem`, `name`
  test, 'anna'
```

Comment: which is unique id of 2nd table v2 or v3

Comment: Both are unique ids

Comment: your desired result is test, 'teena' or test2, 'teena'?

Comment: for f.id =1.,=> ( test, 'anna'), ( test, 'teena'),
|
for f.id =2 =>  (test, 'anna')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should empty the v3 column on insert if v3_amt="" similarly on v2 and try this query

```
Select f.v2,f.v3,f.v2_amt,f.v3_amt,s.name from first as f join second as s on  
(f.v2 = s.id OR f.v3 = s.id) and (f.v2_amt!="" OR f.v3_amt!="") where f.id=2
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `OR`.

```
SELECT f.mem, s.name FROM `first` f JOIN `second` s 
ON f.v2 = s.id AND f.v2_amt !="" OR (f.v3 = s.id AND f.v3_amt !='') 
WHERE f.id = '1'
```

Comment: ok. it works, But only for 1 id of first table.
SELECT f.mem, s.name FROM `first` f JOIN `second` s 
ON f.v2 = s.id AND f.v2_amt !="" OR (f.v3 = s.id AND f.v3_amt !='') 
WHERE f.id = '2' GROUP BY s.id

for the 2 id., it should return as 'test2', 'anna'.
But it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `left join` and `OR` for this case

```
select ft.mem, st.name from first_table ft
LEFT JOIN second_table st ON (ft.v2 = st.id AND ft.v2_amt !="") OR (ft.v3 = st.id AND ft.v3_amt !="")
WHERE ft.id = '1'
```

Comment: Ok. Ques updated. But if f.id = '2'. its returns nothing.